# Twitter Card (photo) is showing error in the validator tool, but all single tags are valid

Tags: twitter, meta-tags

I'm trying to add twitter card support for our own image server. Currently the meta tags are like:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@FotoDish">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@FotoDish">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="FotoDish">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://img.fotodish.com/upload/534d5a08a15537a840cafe8e">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="fotodish.com">
```

as in http://fdi.sh/i/534d5a08a15537a840cafe8e .

However, the validator tool shows error, while all single items are valid.

[image: Twitter Validator Tool result]

What is the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of validator is this? Is it app-only or can it be accessed on a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually find the reason... It was a little tricky and Twitter didn't say anything about it in any docs, which is ....

You need to set the `Content-Type` of the image correctly.

In my situation, I used Amazon S3 and Cloudfront for image storage. When I uploaded the images to S3, I didn't set the MIME type so S3 used `application/octet-stream` as the default value. In this case, the images could be shown in an `img` tag correctly, but would not be treated as an image by Twitter bot.

So I just reset the Content-Type of all the images to 'image/png' (or whatever they should be) and everything was all good.

P.S. Also make sure that you have your `robot.txt` allow `Twitterbot` to access.